# Typing for custom set class

Tags: python-3.x, typing

I'm writing my own version of python's `set`:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Set
T = TypeVar('T')

class MySet(Generic[T]):
    ...
```

However, my IDE complains here:

```
def func(s: Set):
    ...

ms = MySet()
func(ms)  # IDE: complains, "Expected type 'set', got 'MySet' instead
```

If I replace `Generic[T]` with `Set[T]`, then the IDE error goes away, but then `MySet` ends up inheriting all of `set`'s methods, which worries me, as any methods that I don't explicitly override probably won't behave as expected.

What is the correct solution here?

Comment: Of course `def func(s: Set):` will be wrong, `MySet` is not a `Set`, why did you expect it to be?

Comment: I just learned about AbstractSet - seems changing the typing hint for func() to AbstractSet will do the trick.